# Deleting images in images folder of asp mvc application doesn't applied in InternetExplorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp mvc application. it uses some images in images folder in my project as icons. i deleted all these images then run application in Google Chrome browser it doesn't show the icons but when i run the application in Internet Explorer it shows the icons despite i deleted them.the question is Internet Explorer finds the images from where?!

Comment: They have just been cached by the browser.

Comment: I pressed ctrl + F5 several times but no changes is seen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser has cached the image. Open your Temporary Internet Files folder in IE and you will see the cached image. Ctrl-f5 only causes the browser to discard the page cache, not its dependencies like images, scripts, css etc.